# DefaultHttpClient, HttpPost, etc. deprecated. How to post now?

Tags: android

Before Android API 22 i simply did the following:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param url
 * @param params
 * @return
 * @throws ClientProtocolException
 * @throws IOException
 */
public InputStream getStreamFromConnection(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    if(ConnectionDetector.isConnectedToInternet(this.context)) {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "utf-8"));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        return httpEntity.getContent();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Nearly everything in the above code now is deprecated (`NameValuePair`, `DefaultHttpClient`, `HttpPost`, `UrlEncodedFormEntity`, `HttpResponse`, `HttpEntity`, `ClientProtocolException`) and i cant find a recommend way to do in API 22+. How should i do my post now?

Comment: check this post, tihs is the new way o send data http://stackoverflow.com/a/31548224/4987172

Comment: Try to use http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Comment: Use `HttpUrlConnection` or okhttp from square

Comment: Try to use volley. It will automatically handle all connection class internally used in different api level.http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: Use Retrofit! make your life easier.
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use HttpURLConnection now, you can find complete description at below link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: Until now i used name value pairs. i cant change the server side anymore. i implemented everything half a year ago. So the arriving data needs to stay the same. With HttpURLConnection i can send strings so i have to format my string so that the result also is like it was with the namevaluepairs. am i right?

Comment: @Aakash Could you please look into my question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010099/how-to-post-multi-part-form-images-with-string-paramater-in-android/40012227?noredirect=1#comment67307125_40012227

Answer (score 5):

this is an example for async task with POST method:

```
private class SendMessageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Graduate targetGraduate;

    public SendMessageTask(Graduate targetGraduate){
        this.targetGraduate = targetGraduate;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL myUrl = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        String response = "";
        String data = params[0];

        try {
            myUrl = new URL("http://your url");
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            //one long string, first encode is the key to get the  data on your web 
            //page, second encode is the value, keep concatenating key and value.
            //theres another ways which easier then this long string in case you are 
            //posting a lot of info, look it up.
            String postData = URLEncoder.encode("TOKEN", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                    URLEncoder.encode(targetGraduate.getToken(), "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("SENDER_ID", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                    URLEncoder.encode(MainActivity.curretUser.getId(), "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("MESSAGE_DATA", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                    URLEncoder.encode(data, "UTF-8");
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            bufferedWriter.write(postData);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();

            InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            os.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        //do what ever you want with the response
        Log.d("roee", s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Hashmap instead of List. Here's how I do it:

```
HashMap<String,String> contact=new HashMap<>();
contact.put("name",name);
contact.put("address",add);

try{
    URL url=new URL(strURL);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(postDataStr(contact));

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();

    int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
    conn.disconnect();
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        return "success";
    else
        return "";
}catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

postDataStr() is used to convert Hashmap to Encoded String that I copied from somewhere and changed it to suit my app. Below is the code for that:

```
private String postDataStr(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whule all the great answers given by people here will solve your issue, I would strongly recommend you to checkout some awesome (and widely used) network libraries as they'll reduce your work as well as error cases that come with android processes and orientation changes, process killing, etc. You should check out Square's Retrofit library or Google's own Volley for network connections.