# Android Studio connection to Mysql host

Tags: android, mysql

I'm trying to make an app and i need to connect it to an Mysql Hosting to select  and insert data from the application.
I've  been searching around and all i can find is using php files with the code.
If you need more information that i am not givin please ask me!
Thanks!
(i am new with android)

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/31548224/4987172 you have other options in libraries but this is one you can choose

Comment: I am trying to use JDBC to connect, but is giving me this error in the catch com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: show your code or change your question asking about JDBC

Comment: ok, i will create a new question, thanks Rene!