# Get data from android app & Uploading it to localhost server

Tags: android, sql-server, database, localhost

I am new in android app Development my task is to upload data to localhost server that a user will (fill a form & press submit button to) upload.Tell also if any library is needed.

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/ check that tutorial

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518963/sending-image-text-file-from-android-to-webserver-localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using an HTML page? If so it is like a normla html page where you have a form with your fields and a submit button.
If you have, instead, a UI and wants to upload the data to a remove server there are several options:

- Manually
- Using some library (OkHttp or Volley)

If you want to do it manually:

```
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) ( new URL(url)).openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.connect();
        con.getOutputStream().write( ("name=" + name).getBytes());

        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];

        while ( is.read(b) != -1)
            buffer.append(new String(b));

        con.disconnect();
```

Hope it helps you!
If you like i wrote a post about it in [my blog](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/05/android-http-downlod-upload-multipart.html)